# Formatting Title of Table

Tags: tables

### Code

```
\documentclass{statsoc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{The confusion tables for Subject 1} 
    \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
    Bagging\\
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
    \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual  & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 & 
    Speed 5 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
    %heading
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
    Speed 1 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ % inserting body of the table
    Speed 2 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    Speed 3 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 0 \\
    Speed 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 & 0\\
    Speed 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
    \hline\hline %inserts single line 
    Boosting\\
    \hline\hline %inserts single line
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual  & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 & 
    Speed 5 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
    %heading
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
    Speed 1 & 22 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ % inserting body of the table 
    Speed 2 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    Speed 3 & 3 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 0 \\
    Speed 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 23 & 0\\
    Speed 5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 24 \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
    \hline %inserts single line
  \end{tabular}
\label{table:S1_confusion_table} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

### Error

Second Table Labeled Boosting the Title gets left aligned instead of being centered like the Bagging Table.

Comment: please always post a document that reproduces the error, but you presumably got an error from `\hline` which must be used _inside_ `tabular`. After an error, you should ask about the error message not any pdf than might get made, as pdf output after an error is only intended as a debugging aid, not useable output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is the code i used and it gave me the alignment issue. would it be necessary to upload a screenshot of the outputted tables.

Comment: the code above can not be run, it has no `\documentclass`, no `\end{tabular}`

Comment: if add `\documentclass{article}` it gives the error `! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=\`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.8 \hline
          \hline %inserts double horizontal lines`  After an error do not even look at the PDF, TeX makes no attempt to make sensible PDF output if you scroll past an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok I have added a documentclass, end tabular and table statement so the code can run

Comment: so as you will see it generates an error (at which point it's best to stop tex rather than scrolling past the error)  if you delete the `\hline\hline` it runs without error but you talk as if there are two tables you only have one, `Bagging` is before the `tabular` but `Boosting` is inside the tabular, so naturally they are formatted differently. perhaps you want two tables?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh i see. Yes I want two tables with Bagging on top then right below Boosting on bottom with both titles centered

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

using `article` document class the *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}
    \centering      % <---
    \begin{table}
        \caption{The confusion tables for Subject 1}
    %\hline\hline % works only inside tabular ; inserts double horizontal lines
    \begin{tabular}{c c  c c  c c} % centered columns (6! not 4 columns)
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Bagging}     \\
    \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual
        & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 & Speed 5 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
    %heading
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
    Speed 1 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ % inserting body of the table
    Speed 2 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    Speed 3 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 0 \\
    Speed 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 & 0\\
    Speed 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
    \hline\hline %inserts single line
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Boostingm}\\
    \hline\hline %inserts single line
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual  & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 &
    Speed 5 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
    %heading
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
    Speed 1 & 22 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ % inserting body of the table
    Speed 2 & 0 & 25 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    Speed 3 & 3 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 0 \\
    Speed 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 23 & 0\\
    Speed 5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 24 \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
    \hline %inserts single line
  \end{tabular}
\label{table:S1_confusion_table} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

`\hline` should not to be outside `tabular`. for centering of "title" you should use `\multicolumn` environment.

**edit:**
your table i would design with help of `booktbs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
        \caption{The confusion tables for Subject 1}
    \begin{tabular}{c c  c c  c c} % centered columns (6! not 4 columns)
        \toprule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Bagging}     \\
        \midrule
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual
        & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 & Speed 5 \\ 
    %heading
    \hline % inserts single horizontal line
    Speed 1 & 24 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\ 
    Speed 2 &  0 & 25 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
    Speed 3 &  0 &  0 & 25 &  0 &  0 \\
    Speed 4 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 24 &  0 \\
    Speed 5 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 25 \\ 
        \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Boostingm}\\
        \midrule
    Predicted \textbackslash Actual  & Speed 1 &  Speed 2 &  Speed 3 & Speed 4 &
    Speed 5 \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
    %heading
        \midrule 
    Speed 1 & 22 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\ % inserting body of the table
    Speed 2 &  0 & 25 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
    Speed 3 &  3 &  0 & 24 &  0 &  0 \\
    Speed 4 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 23 &  0\\
    Speed 5 &  0 &  0 &  1 &  0 & 24 \\ 
        \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\label{table:S1_confusion_table} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: yes that is correct. and that works better then statsoc. thank you very much

Comment: the caption "Table 1: The confusion tables for Subject 1" is centered but the tables are left aligned. how would this be fixed?

Comment: @AllenRahrooh, with adding `\centering` after `\begin{table}` corrected in answer.